# How Can I Edit My Array's For Loop To Reflrect This?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My array's for loop currently results in numbers like: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ....to 1000.

Here is the code:

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 1000 ; i = i++)
        [pickerArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]]
```

I want it instead, to have the following pattern, 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 20, etc.

And it is displayed using this code:

```
float weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f lb", weight];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
for ( float i = 0.0 ; i <= 1000.0 ; i = i + 2.5)
{
    //[pickerArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", i]]
    [pickerArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:i];
}


float weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", weight];
```

Comment: thanks can you try editing the display code I just added in the question? thanks

Comment: I agree that NSNumber is probably a more sensible storage type, but you need to explicitly convert to float on the way out -- I've taken the liberty of fixing this in your code.

Comment: this works but it is showing 2.5000000 lb, etc.  Any way to make it just 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, etc instead of 5.0000000 lb

Comment: @Faisal Oh FFS. Use the "%.1f" format string seen throughout all these answers. Do you really expect SO to write every single character of your program?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1001];
for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i)
    [pickerArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", 2.5*i]]
```

Comment: I don't get the 700 vs 1000... What's to goal of this difference ?

Comment: @Rabskatran just copypasted the code from question. That difference makes no sense really

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the loop:

```
for ( float f = 0; f <= 1000; f = f + 2.5 )
    [pickerArray adObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", f]];
```

Or you can just multiply it when creating the strings:

```
    [pickerArray adObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", 2.5*i]];
```

Also, if you are immediately putting 1000 objects in, why start with an initial capacity of 700? And are you really sure you want all those strings in this array?

EDIT: and having looked at your edit, are you really sure you want to do this seemingly-redundant conversion back and forth to strings? Well, if you're sure:

```
float weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
```

Comment: well it is for weight for exercises, I guess I really only need to go to 700 lb or so.

Comment: sorry, the display code actually needs to be edited too, that is just the old one i posted.

Comment: @Faisal No it isn't. You need to pay attention to the details if you're going to write code.